# Is there a way to run gremlin.js Monkey Tests on third party URLs?

Tags: javascript, testing, fuzzing, monkey-testing, gremlinjs

Is it possible to run Gremlin tests on third party URLs or external websites? For e.g. If I want to run gremlin on Twitter.com, what would I have to do? I've not tried it yet, but I'm thinking a framework like nightwatch.js might be handy, but I'm not sure about how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized since posting this question that like @ste_irl has answered, using gremlin as a bookmarklet is the answer for most sites. But one big *if* here is that if the site implements a content security policy on [`script-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), the bookmarklet wouldn't work.

To get around this, this is what I did:
 - Download Mozilla Developer Edition
 - Set `security.csp.enable` to `false`

This still doesn't work on Facebook, but works on `inbox.google.com` and most other websites

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as a bookmark in your browser:

https://rawgit.com/marmelab/gremlins.js/master/bookmarklet.html

This will let you run it on any website.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I came across this, but realized that it doesn't work on _all_ websites. If CSP (content security policy) is implemented, this script won't work. For e.g. Facebook, inbox etc.